# Posso passar 2 array_encode Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Eu consigo passar 2 `json_encode` em uma única função no *Laravel*?
 Qual a melhor forma de retornar 2 *JSON* diferentes?
Sendo que 1 consulta a tabela Produtos e a outra a tabela Estados.

Olha como esta meu controller:

```
   $data = Produtos::select(
                      DB::raw('nome as nome'),
                      DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
                    ->groupBy('nome')
                    ->get();

    $array[] = ['Nome', 'Number'];

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $array[++$key] = [$value->nome, $value->number];
    }

    /**
    * CALCULO DOS ESTADOS
    */

    $estados = Estados::selectRaw('SUM(valor) as valor, estado as estado')->groupBy('estado')->get();
    $arrayEstados[] = ['Valor', 'Estado'];
    foreach($estados as $key => $valor) {
        $arrayEstados[++$key] = [$valor->valor, $valor->estado];

    }

    return view('home', compact('notasEntrada', 'notasSaida', 'valorNotasEntrada', 'valorNotasSaida'))->with('nome', json_encode($array), 'estados', json_encode($arrayEstados));

}
```

Perceba que no `return view` estou passando 2 `json_encode` mas não estou tenho resultado, isso é permitido fazer? Qual a melhor solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente passar o **return** desta forma:

```
return view('home', compact('notasEntrada', 'notasSaida', 'valorNotasEntrada', 'valorNotasSaida'))->with('nome', json_encode($array))->with('estados', json_encode($arrayEstados));
```

É possível enviar 2 `with();` ou até mais, conforme a necessidade.

Referencia: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: vou tentar, já já te respondo @Bulfaitelo

Comment: Deu certo @Bulfaitelo, obrigado pela ajuda!